# materialize sidenav is appearing but nothing happened when clicking on it even after using jquery

Tags: jquery, materialize, sidenav

HTML code

```
 <a href="#" class="sidenav-trigger" data-target="mobile-links">
            <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
        </a><ul class="sidenav" id="mobile-links">
    <li><a href="home.html">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">my profile</a></li>
</ul>
```

I used the below jquery
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js

Jquery code

```
    $(document).ready(function(){$('.sidenav').sidenav();})
```

Comment: Your code is working just fine: https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/abvKdRV

Comment: I have just found the error
https://ibb.co/cJLmSn0

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. You just have to load jQuery first before you load materialize.min.js.